# How to summarize multiple data frames quickly in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, summary

Thanks in advance for any help on this.  I am trying to simply summarize multiple data frames in R  I have a file that I am reading in that has an output like this:

```
             NDC CHARGE GENERIC
4060 68382006401  43.34    true
4061 68382006401  95.04    true
4062 68382006410  16.77   false
```

I save the .csv file that being read to the variable "data".  Once I read the data I separate it into two other variables ("true" and "false") depending on if the GENERIC column is true or false.  What I want to do is summarize some of the columns in the three different data frames efficiently.  Currently I use:

```
sapply(data[,1:2], summarize)
sapply(true[,1:2], summarize)
sapply(false[,1:2], summarize)
```

to summarize the data. This method is fine for right now, but I am going to have a lot more variables and it seems like I should just be able to loop it or concatenate the data frames some how.

Comment: `summarize` is probably in a package (perhaps even Hmisc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can put the `data.frames` in a list, e.g.

```
dat <- data.frame(x=1:5,y=5:1)

datlist <- list(dat,dat,dat)
```

then you can run function over all the data.frames with `lapply`:

```
lapply(datlist, function(x) sapply(x[,1:2], summary))
```

A nice easy way to bring all the results back together into one `data.frame` is with the package `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
ldply(datlist, function(x) sapply(x[,1:2], summary))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, given the various ambiguities in this question, but perhaps:

```
sapply(data[,1:2], summarize)
sapply(data[data$GENERIC="true", 1:2], summarize)
sapply(data[data$GENERIC="false", 1:2], summarize)
```

It's better to name data opbjects something other than "data". There's even a fortune on that topic that makes mirth in perpetuity of such naming behaviors

```
 install.packages("fortunes")
 require("fortunes")
 fortune("dog")
```